# Issue with visibility of bucketable items on multi-server CM environments in sitecore

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore8

**Issue:** When items are moved from one bucket folder to another on one CM server, they get disappeared from second CM server

**A brief introduction:**

We are having two CM servers set up for our website - CM1 and CM2. We have an Item bucket that stores items with three nested folders:year,month,day. 
The item is initially created with the creation date and we have a custom path resolver which updates the path of the item according to a field 'Due Date' and then moves the item into a new bucket whenever the 'Due Date' field is modified and the item saved.

The following code is run on item saved:

```
         /*move the saved item according to release/due date*/
         BucketManager.MoveItemIntoBucket(savedItem, bucketItem);
        /*delete previous parent if it has no child (delete empty buckets)*/
        if (BucketManager.IsItemContainedWithinBucket(removeItem))
        {
            if (!removeItem.HasChildren)
            {
                removeItem.Delete();
            }
        }
```

The following setting is done to implement the GetFolderPath method of interface IDynamicBucketFolderPath(Sitecore.Buckets.dll) according to 'Due Date':

```
<setting name="BucketConfiguration.DynamicBucketFolderPath">
    <patch:attribute name="value">  FullyQualifiedPathOfTheClassWithGetFolderPathMethod, AssemblyName    </patch:attribute>
</setting>
```

**Problem Description:**

1. When we create an item in the item bucket on CM1 server, the item gets created within the year, month and day folders getting created with current date.
   If the same item is checked on CM2 server, it is visible there.
   Initially the ‘Due Date’ field is blank.
2. When the 'Due Date' field is modified with a new date on CM1 server and the item is saved, the item moves into newly created bucket folders with the date strutcure as of 'Due Date'.
   If the same item is checked on CM2 server, it is now not present there.

It seems that the items are not getting synced on both servers with the MoveItemIntoBucket method of BucketManager class present in Sitecore.Buckets.dll.

If we now do 'Update Item' from the developer ribbon in Content Editor of CM1 for the same item, the same starts to appear on CM2 server but we do not want to manually do an 'Update Item' whenever a new bucketable item is created.

What could be causing this behavior? How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have the scaling configs enabled for both CM servers?

Comment: I am not able to see the item even in Content Editor of the second server. When the item is initially created on one CM server, it is available at the same path in the content editor of second CM server too but once I update the 'Release date' field and then item moves into another bucket with a new date, it gets vanished from the Content Editor of second CM server( while it is available in the content editor of first CM server at the newly created path) Would scaling config help here ? We had tried rebuilding the index manually on another server too but it did not work.

Comment: To add to this, whenever an item is moved to an existing folder structure, it is visible in the Content Editor of both servers, the issue occurs only when new bucket folders with year,month in the 'Release Date' get created on changing the release date. So, the problem is with the folders not getting updated on another server due to which the item is not visible.

Answer (score 1):

Based your description I believe you have not enabled the Scaling settings for your Content Management servers.  Unlike normal Items in Sitecore, the interface for Bucketed items relies heavily on search.  Assuming you are using the out of the box Lucene implementation each CM server maintains its own index. Without the Scaling configuration enabled, only the server that the change is made on will update its search index.  The scaling configuration will enabled events so remote servers are aware of those changes as well.

Page 24 of the [Sitecore Search Scaling Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/sitecore_search_scaling%20guide_sc7-a4.pdf) describes how to enable the Scaling configuration and what settings are available.  Please make sure you have the Sitecore.Buckets.Scaling.config enabled for both Content Management servers.

The same will apply if you have multiple CD servers, so make sure to enable the appropriate scaling configs for those servers as well.